# Python 3.X package distribution and config files

Tags: python, pip, packaging, resource-files

My goal is to create Python package from my project that copies config file into user home directory during pip install.

Example:
`pip install my_project`

Result:

```
    1. my_project installed in site-packages
    2. file system.yaml copied into ~/system.yaml
```

Structure :

```
  my_project/
       src/ - all code
       config/ - configuration files
```

Python 3.8

Packaging tool : setuptools + wheels

Configuration file : my_project/config/system.yaml

Q: What is a pythonic way to solve this issue?

*PS: I know how to do it on runtime but I need it during "pip install" time*

Thanks

Comment: "*I need it during "pip install" time*" No, you don't. Think about a package installed into a virtualenv — it must not copy config to the user home.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I am thinking about these possibilities as it looks there is no direct way. Install is not configuration but I guess you need something similar to 'apt install'. Not only install but also populate default config files in some editable, predictable place

- first add simple example file using data-files=[] directove
- write simple code at the end of setup.py file
- or write something more sophisticated to extend setup.py functionality
- https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files
- https://jichu4n.com/posts/how-to-add-custom-build-steps-and-commands-to-setuppy/

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem right now. My turnaround is to do create a `config.py` that contains something like the following:

```
import pathlib

try:
    with open(pathlib.Path.home().joinpath(".mypackage/config.toml"), mode="rb") as fp:
        data = tomllib.load(fp)
    MY_CONSTANT = data["my_constant"]
    ANOTHER_CONST = data["another_constant"]
except FileNotFoundError:
    MY_CONSTANT = 0.0
    ANOTHER_CONST = "potato"
```

and then explaining in the documentation how to add a custom config file.
Hope it helps!